# AngularJS module app dependency

Tags: arrays, angularjs, dependency-injection

I have declared twp app modules in my app.js file-"requestDashboard" and "newRequestDashboard"..."newRequestDashboard" is dependent upon "requestDashboard"(I have an array of objects that I'd like to display. Both of the apps have a different controller assigned to them and the array is stored in "requestDashboard". I maybe trying to overcomplicate this but I cannot for some reason display any of the objects. Code below:

app.js:

```
angular.module( 'requestDashboard', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);

angular.module( 'newRequestDashboard', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'requestDashboard']);
```

Controller in "requestDashboard"

```
angular.module("requestDashboard")
.controller( 'requestDashboardCtrl', function ($scope) {

    //Dummy Data for user requests
    $scope.requests = [
        {
            type: "meeting1",
            meetingName: "Radiology San Diego",
            location:"Sheraton Ballroom 5S",
            subitems: [
                {
                    name: "ESCALATED",
                    desc: "Power strips at every table",
                    priority:"1",
                    planner:"Jessica Q. Planner",
                    time:"02/15/15 at 8:15 AM",
                    quantity:"3; one power strip at ever table"

                },
                {
                    name: "OPEN",
                    desc: "Extra table for 3",
                    priority:"3",
                    planner:"Jessica Q. Planner"
                },
                {
                    name: "ACKNOWLEDGED",
                    desc: "Projector for meeting",
                    priority:"2",
                    planner:"Jessica Q. Planner"
                },
                {
                    name: "CLOSED",
                    desc: "book exta room for 2 guests",
                    priority:"5",
                    planner:"Jessica Q. Planner"
                },
                {
                    name: "CANCELLED",
                    desc: "extra chairs",
                    priority:"1",
                    planner:"Jessica Q. Planner"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            type: "meeting2",
            meetingName: "California Almond Growers",
            location:"Sheraton FL14",
            subitems: [
                {
                    name: "ESCALATED",
                    desc: "need some more almonds",
                    priority:"1",
                    planner:"Jessica Q. Planner"
                },
                {
                    name: "OPEN",
                    desc: "extra pamphlets",
                    priority:"4",
                    planner:"Jessica Q. Planner"
                },
                {
                    name: "ACKNOWLEDGED",
                    desc: "Power supply",
                    priority:"2",
                    planner:"Jessica Q. Planner"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            type: "meeting3",
            meetingName: "Association of Amateur Archaeologists",
            location:"Ansley 1- FL14",
            subitems: [
                {
                    name: "ESCALATED",
                    desc: "need some more experience",
                    priority:"1",
                    planner:"Jessica Q. Planner"
                },
                {
                    name: "OPEN",
                    desc: "need dinosaurs",
                    priority:"3",
                    planner:"Jessica Q. Planner"
                }
            ]
        }
    ];


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very common to have many apps in your application. But you should take a different approach to this. In your solution you are declaring dependency on all your app. Which will conflict if your application gets bigger. What you should so is something like this.

```
// declare your app without any dependency 
(function() {
    var requestDashboard= angular.module( 'requestDashboard',[]);
}());

(function() {
    var newRequestDashboard= angular.module( 'newRequestDashboard',[]);
}());


// inject all your dependency here
var mainApp = angular.module( 'mainApp ', ['requestDashboard','newRequestDashboard','ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

About your question, Why don't you use Services? and services can be consumed in controller and then you can display back to your view.

Hope this helps

Comment: good point on the service +1...but regarding the service, the array would be used in two different controllers that are in two different modules. How would i go about to set that service if it were that case? Also, "requestDashboard" in your answer was injected twice?